# What is the JCC instruction in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, opcode, mnemonics

I only know instructions like je, jnl, etc., in  x86 AT&T syntax.

What does jcc actually mean?  All jump instructions?

Comment: Usually the documentation answers such a question on a single glimpse...

Comment: I think it's just the generic form, where `j` means "jump" and `cc` means condition code, which can be any of the usual ones, `z`, `nz`, etc.

Comment: CC stands for the condition, not a condition itself http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_146.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCC#Programming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cc` stands for `condition code`.

`Jcc` is not a single instruction, it just describes the [jump mnemonics](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall12/cos375/IA32Jcc.pdf) that check the condition code before jumping.

`JNE` for instance, checks the condition code before jumping.

The typical case is to do a comparison (which sets the CC) and then use one of the jump mnemonics afterwards.

The condition code can also be set with instructions like `AND`, `OR`, `XOR`, addition, subtraction (or `CMP`, of course).

Answer (score 3):

CC means condition code.  Normally this means the state of FLAGS, except for JECXZ, which Intel groups with the other Jcc instructions in the [Jcc insn set ref manual entry](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html).

Other manuals, like [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize), often separate JECXZ from the flag-based jumps, because they perform differently.

> All jump instructions?

No, definitely not.

x86 also has another conditional jump instruction: [LOOP/LOOPcc](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LOOP:LOOPcc.html).  LOOPE LOOPNE are the only conditions available, not the full set of flag states.  ([Don't use LOOP, it's slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently))

Jcc also doesn't include JMP or any other **unconditional** jumps, even indirect jumps (e.g. `jmp *rax` in AT&T syntax).  Indirect jumps are always taken, but can have a variable destination.  CALL and RET are also jumps.

Even [XBEGIN](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XBEGIN.html) operates as a jump if a [transactional memory operation](http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-tm/) aborts before reaching an XEND instruction, so it's a conditional branch on the transaction committing or aborting.

---

There are other "cc" instruction that use the same FLAGS conditions as conditional jumps: [SETcc](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SETcc.html) and [CMOVcc](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMOVcc.html).  Just like Jcc, FLAGS are a data input to those instructions, and their data output depends on it.  So you can do flag-based stuff without jumps.

---

The terminology isn't restricted to just x86:

GNU C inline assembly syntax also [uses `"cc"` to declare that an inline-asm statement clobbers the machine's condition codes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers).  (This is implicit on x86 and x86-64: you never need an explicit `"cc"` clobber.  Unlike some architectures (e.g. ARM), most x86 instructions modify flags, so when gcc was ported to x86, the designers decided that it was unlikely to help make better code, and much more likely to be a source of bugs when people forgot to write `"cc"` in the clobber section.)